# Need Help Displaying Token and NFT Holdings in Solana Dapp Portfolio

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, token, balance, walletadapter

I'm currently working on a Solana Dapp portfolio project where users can connect their wallets and view their token and NFT holdings. I am done making the wallet connection buttons and installing Solana Web3.js and SPL tokens for browser use. However, I've been getting  a problem when I want to display holdings of tokens other than SOL.

I've seen YouTube tutorials and documentation, but I couldn't find a comprehensive solution for fetching and displaying the holdings of various tokens in a Solana wallet. While I can retrieve the SOL balance using the getAccountInfo() function, I'm struggling to find a similar method for other tokens in the wallet.

If anyone in the community has experience or insights on how to achieve this, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Sharing code examples or pointing me in the right direction in the Solana documentation would be incredibly helpful. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I wanna do this in Javascript, that will be used in browser, not in node.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use this method: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner

You can use it in JS

Comment: Thanks, let me try this method. But I think this doesn't let us fetch name, metadata and symbol of tokens, I am using this method already in typescript in previous projects, it gives Token Address, mint Acount address and balance in wallet. But Donot Give other info about token.

Comment: no that's 2 separate things, first you get  token accounts and balances, then you look for the metadata for each token

Comment: Oh, I thought this method should give u all the metadata, Can I know whats method for NFT fetch, whole, I mean is there even a method we can use that we give wallet address, the code gives us NFT all info, metadata etc., I searched stack exchange not found any. its becoming difficult for me. But anyhow now I know that Metadata and Token Address are 2 Different things, thanks for this info.

Comment: as far as i know, there is not a method. May be in metaplex/js, but not sure. check metaplex/js to decode data, it's quite easy now with their js library